# Swift UI Draggable price indicator does not move to edges correctly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, graph

I am making a simple robin hood clone in Swift UI. When the user holds down and swipes left or right on the graph a line indicator pops up to show the price at the specific point. On some assets like BTC and ETH the price indicator works just fine.

On other assets that have different graphs and data the line indicator doesn't move all the way to the left and right edge (stops a little before or goes over). I've been messing around with the onChanged method to try and fix this. I haven't had any luck.

I tried setting **offset.width = value.location.x**, this didn't work either. I also modified the .offset modifier but was not able to get it working right: **.offset(x: offset.width > 0 && offset.width < proxy.size.width - 68 ? offset.width : offset.width <= 0 ? 0 : offset.width >= proxy.size.width - 68 ? proxy.size.width - 68 : offset.width)**.

The only relevant code to look at is the overlay and gesture inside **LineGraph**. Ive included other code to reproduce the problem, just ignore it though.

```
import SwiftUI

struct someMainView: View {
   @Namespace var animation
   @StateObject var appModel = StockViewModel()

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           if let coins = appModel.coins {
               ForEach(coins){ coin in
                   NavigationLink {
                       AllStockView(coin: coin)
                   } label: {
                       Text("\(coin.name)").font(.title)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

struct AllStockView: View {
   @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
   @Namespace var animation
   let coin: CryptoModel

   var body: some View {
       VStack(spacing: 5){
           ScrollView {
               VStack {
                   GraphView(coin: coin).frame(height: 500)
               }
           }
           .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).scrollIndicators(.hidden)
       }
   }
   
   @ViewBuilder
   func GraphView(coin: CryptoModel)->some View{
       GeometryReader { _ in
           LineGraph(data: coin.last_7days_price.price,profit: coin.price_change > 0)
       }
       .padding(.bottom,20)
   }
}

struct LineGraph: View {
   @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
   var data: [Double]
   var profit: Bool = false
   @State var currentPlot = ""
   @State var offset: CGSize = .zero
   @State var showPlot = false
   @GestureState var isDrag: Bool = false
   @State var graphProgress: CGFloat = 0
   
   var body: some View {
       GeometryReader { proxy in
           let height = proxy.size.height
           let width = (proxy.size.width) / CGFloat(data.count - 1)
           
           let maxPoint = (data.max() ?? 0)
           let minPoint = data.min() ?? 0
           
           let points = data.enumerated().compactMap { item -> CGPoint in

               let progress = (item.element - minPoint) / (maxPoint - minPoint)
               
               let pathHeight = progress * (height - 50)

               let pathWidth = width * CGFloat(item.offset)

               return CGPoint(x: pathWidth, y: -pathHeight + height)
           }
           ZStack{
               AnimatedGraphPath(progress: graphProgress, points: points)
                   .fill(
                       LinearGradient(colors: [
                           profit ? .green : .red,
                           profit ? .green : .red,
                       ], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing)
                   )
               FillBG()
                   .clipShape (
                       Path { path in
                           path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                           
                           path.addLines(points)
                           
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: proxy.size.width, y: height))
                           
                           path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height))
                       }
                   )
                   .opacity(graphProgress)
           }
           //------------------here-----------------------------------
           .overlay (
               VStack(spacing: 0){
                   Text(currentPlot)
                       .font(.caption.bold())
                       .foregroundStyle(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(UIColor.lightGray) : .gray)
                       .padding(.vertical, 6)
                       .offset(x: offset.width > 0 && offset.width < proxy.size.width - 68 ? offset.width : offset.width <= 0 ? 0 : offset.width >= proxy.size.width - 68 ? proxy.size.width - 68 : offset.width)
                       
                   Rectangle()
                       .fill(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(UIColor.lightGray) : .gray)
                       .frame(width: 1,height: widthOrHeight(width: false) * 0.42)
                       .offset(x: offset.width)
                   Spacer()
               }
               .offset(y: 45)
               .opacity(showPlot ? 1 : 0), alignment: .bottomLeading
           )
           .contentShape(Rectangle())
           .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
               withAnimation { showPlot = true }
               let translation = value.location.x
               let index = max(min(Int((translation / width).rounded() + 1), data.count - 1), 0)
               
               currentPlot = data[index].convertToCurrency()
               offset = CGSize(width: points[index].x - 35, height: points[index].y - height)
           }).onEnded({ value in
               
               withAnimation{showPlot = false}
               
           }).updating($isDrag, body: { value, out, _ in
               out = true
           }))
       }//-------------------here --------------------------------------
       .onChange(of: isDrag) { newValue in
           if !isDrag {
               showPlot = false
           } else {
               UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()
           }
       }
       .onAppear {
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
               withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)){
                   graphProgress = 1
               }
           }
       }
       .onChange(of: data) { newValue in
           graphProgress = 0
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
               withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)){
                   graphProgress = 1
               }
           }
       }
   }

   @ViewBuilder
   func FillBG()->some View {
       let color: Color = profit ? .green : .red
       LinearGradient(colors: [
           color
               .opacity(0.3),
           color
               .opacity(0.2),
           color
               .opacity(0.1)]
           + Array(repeating: color
               .opacity(0.1), count: 4)
           + Array(repeating:                     Color.clear, count: 2)
           , startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
   }
}

struct AnimatedGraphPath: Shape{
   var progress: CGFloat
   var points: [CGPoint]
   var animatableData: CGFloat{
       get{return progress}
       set{progress = newValue}
   }
   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
       Path { path in

           path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
           
           path.addLines(points)
       }
       .trimmedPath(from: 0, to: progress)
       .strokedPath(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2.5, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
   }
}
class StockViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var coins: [CryptoModel]?
   @Published var currentCoin: CryptoModel?
   
   init(){
       Task{
           do {
               try await fetchCryptoData()
           } catch{
               print(error.localizedDescription)
           }
       }
   }

   func fetchCryptoData() async throws {
       let url = URL(string: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24h")
       
       guard let url = url else { return }
       let session = URLSession.shared
       
       let response = try await session.data(from: url)
       let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([CryptoModel].self, from: response.0)
       
       await MainActor.run(body: {
           self.coins = jsonData
           if let firstCoin = jsonData.first {
               self.currentCoin = firstCoin
           }
       })
   }
}

struct CryptoModel: Identifiable,Codable{
   var id: String
   var symbol: String
   var name: String
   var current_price: Double
   var last_updated: String
   var price_change: Double
   var last_7days_price: GraphModel
   
   enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
       case id
       case symbol
       case name
       case current_price
       case last_updated
       case price_change = "price_change_percentage_24h"
       case last_7days_price = "sparkline_in_7d"
   }
}

struct GraphModel: Codable{
   var price: [Double]
   enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey{
       case price
   }
}
```